# pandas to_datetime('today') throwing error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the current day using pandas.to_datetime('today') but I am getting the following error:
"AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute 'now'"
I looked it up and apparently, it is valid and should be working correctly. Can anyone suggest a solution, please? (pandas version 0.25.3)

Thanks in advance

Comment: So if you open a perfectly new python environment and type `import pandas as pd; pd.to_datetime('today')` you get that same error?

Comment: Great point. I tried and updated the version of pandas and it worked. I was worried about the dependencies and that is why I did not do that in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues with timestamps on [Pandas 0.25.3](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.25.3/) and [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html) as well.

While all works well on Pandas 0.25.3 up to and including [Python 3.8.x](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), many timestamp operations break on Python 3.9. Here's an example of the first issue I ran into:

```py
$ pip install pandas==0.25.3
Collecting pandas==0.25.3
Collecting pytz>=2017.2
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1
Collecting six>=1.5
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.2 pandas-0.25.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 six-1.15.0
$ python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 19 2020, 14:01:03) 
[GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)] on linux
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Timestamp
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
>>> pd.Timestamp.utcnow
<bound method Timestamp.utcnow of <class 'type'>>
>>> pd.Timestamp.utcnow()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx", line 303, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.utcnow
AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute 'now'
```

I couldn't find any Pandas [issue reports](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?q=is%3Aissue) or [pull requests](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pulls?q=is%3Apr) related to this.

The next binary wheel available on the PyPI for Pandas after version 0.25.3 seems to be [1.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.1.3/), and with that version timestamp operations work as expected.